# inner string array filter in array object with string arrry

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
var mainobj=[[{
      "title": "Nifty News: Dapper Labs pursuing DAOs, Bundesliga partners with Sorare, and more. ",
    
      "category": [
        "Dapper Labs",
        " Brud",
        " Sorare",
        " Bundesliga",
        " Etched",
        " Hockey Diversity Alliance",
        " Archdiocese of Bangkok NFT"
      ],
      "description": "Nifty News: Dapper Labs pursuing DAOs, Bundesliga partners with Sorare, and more. ",
  
    },
    {
      "title": "Bitcoin returns to $1T asset as BTC price blasts to $55K",
     
      "category": [
        "Bitcoin",
        " BTC price"
      ],
      "description": "Bitcoin returns to $1T asset as BTC price blasts to $55K",
      
    }]]

var categoryfilterArray=['Bitcoin','Bundesliga','Sorare']
```

i need filter which match categoryfilterArray in mainobj

Comment: Your description of the problem does not appear to be formatted correctly. I am also willing to bet that if you were to format the code as `code`, you would be met with the warning that too much of your description is code and you did not describe the error and desired output well enough. I look forward to seeing the question after your edits 

Comment: Can you give an example of what the desired output would look like?

Comment: Are you trying to match all items in the `categoryfilterArray`? or only some of the items?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm assuming you don't actually have an array containing another array, rather a single array of objects, as such:

```js
const mainobj = [
  {
    title: "Nifty News: Dapper Labs pursuing DAOs, Bundesliga partners with Sorare, and more. ",
    category: [
      "Dapper Labs",
      "Brud",
      "Sorare",
      "Bundesliga",
      "Etched",
      "Hockey Diversity Alliance",
      "Archdiocese of Bangkok NFT"
    ],
    description: "Nifty News: Dapper Labs pursuing DAOs, Bundesliga partners with Sorare, and more. ",
  },
  {
    title: "Bitcoin returns to $1T asset as BTC price blasts to $55K",
    category: [
      "Bitcoin",
      "BTC price"
    ],
    description: "Bitcoin returns to $1T asset as BTC price blasts to $55K",
  }
];
```

From there, you can look at the intersection of the `category` array and your `categoryfilterArray` using a function like so:

```js
const arrayIntersection = (array1, array2) => {
  return array1.filter(x => array2.includes(x));
};
```

Then it comes down to how you compare the intersection.

If you're trying find objects where the `categories` contains all of the `categoryfilterArray` values, you would compare the intersecting array as a string:

```js
const matchingObj = mainobj.filter(obj => {
  return JSON.stringify(arrayIntersection(obj.category, categoryfilterArray)) === JSON.stringify(categoryfilterArray);
});
```

If you're only looking for one or more of the target categories in the intersection, you can use a boolean conversion:

```js
const matchingObj = mainobj.filter(obj => {
  return Boolean(arrayIntersection(obj.category, categoryfilterArray).length);
});
```

Any intersection length greater than `0` will return `true`, and return the object in the filter. Alternatively, you can check for  `arrayIntersection(obj.category, categoryfilterArray).length > 0`.

Working examples: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hew9bq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank for your replay but its not working

Comment: if i filter with var categoryfilterArray=[''Bundesliga','Sorare']  Return will be {
    title: "Nifty News: Dapper Labs pursuing DAOs, Bundesliga partners with Sorare, and more. ",
    category: [
      "Dapper Labs",
      "Brud",
      "Sorare",
      "Bundesliga",
      "Etched",
      "Hockey Diversity Alliance",
      "Archdiocese of Bangkok NFT"
    ],
    description: "Nifty News: Dapper Labs pursuing DAOs, Bundesliga partners with Sorare, and more. ",
  }

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sample code. I added a StackBlitz with examples. What you still haven't indicated is what you're trying to match on. Are you trying to find objects with **all** matching categories? or **some** matching categories?